# Issue with my SQL code to remove an entry from an SQL database

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am writing a program for practice that allows me to edit a database. I have it so that it loads and displays the data and I have it so that it can add entry's. I am now having issues with deleting an entry, my code is below, and when I run it I get an error that says:org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error), I have looked through the code and I don't see any errors.

```
            @FXML
            private void selectStudent(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException{
    StudentData stud = studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String sqlRemove = "DELETE FROM Students(id, fname, lname, email, dob) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        if (stud != null) {
           Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
           PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sqlRemove);

            st.setString(1, this.idcolumn.getText());
            st.setString(2, this.fnamecolumn.getText());
            st.setString(3, this.lnamecolumn.getText());
            st.setString(4, this.emailcolumn.getText());
            st.setString(5, this.dobcolumn.getText());

            st.execute();
            conn.close();
        } else {
            test.setText("Please select an Entry");
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query looks like a mix between a _delete_ and an _insert_ query. Try `"DELETE FROM Students WHERE id = ? "` and only set the `id` value :  (`st.setString(1, this.idcolumn.getText());`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Students(id, fname, lname, email, dob) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

is Not a valid Delete query , Try to run the same in sqlLite you will get to know.

It should be `DELETE FROM Students where (pass any of one condition which returns a row value) i.e. id=?`